# Check if a string is a valid Python object path

Tags: python

Sometimes you need to dynamically import Python objects, for example with `importlib`:

```
import importlib
importlib.import_module(name='my.module.path')
```

I would like to know if there is a standard way to check if the string fed to `importlib.import_module` is **valid**, i.e. could specify the location of a Python object.

If I had to implement a validation method myself, I would try to match the string against a regular expression like `([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]\.?)+` (names starting with letters or underscore, composed of letters, underscores and numbers, and separated by dots).

Is there a method in standard or third libraries to check this? If not, is there a PEP describing valid Python paths? If not, is my regex sufficient?

Comment: As long as it follows dot notation and English alphabet lowercase/uppercase it is good

Comment: What do you mean by valid, that it doesn't throw an format error when passed to `importlib.import_module()`???

Comment: Define 'valid'? E.g. following the rules for module names (so valid Python identifiers), or referring to an actual importable object?

Comment: And you can't validate dotted names like this without actually *doing the import*, because plenty of modules set such names dynamically. For example, `os.path` is dynamically set when you import `os`, it is really either the `ntpath` or the `posixpath` module!

Comment: By valid, I mean that the object **could** be imported if it exists. I don't need to know if it **actually** exists.

Comment: @Pawamoy: then all you need to validate is that you have Python identifiers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `import` statement requires that names are *valid Python identifiers*. From the [`import` statement documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement):

> ```
> import_stmt     ::=  "import" module ["as" name] ( "," module ["as" name] )*
>                      | "from" relative_module "import" identifier ["as" name]
>                      ( "," identifier ["as" name] )*
>                      | "from" relative_module "import" "(" identifier ["as" name]
>                      ( "," identifier ["as" name] )* [","] ")"
>                      | "from" module "import" "*"
> module          ::=  (identifier ".")* identifier
> relative_module ::=  "."* module | "."+
> name            ::=  identifier
> ```

Identifiers are basically anything that starts with a letter or underscore, followed by 0 or more letters, underscores or digits. The definition of letters and digits is broad, see the [*Identifiers and keywords* section](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers); basically the NFKC normalised forms of specific Unicode character classes are all included.

However, note that by using `importlib()`, **anything goes**. You can import modules that do not have valid Python identifier names, because the whole process is highly flexible. If you want to import a module that only consists of digits, then *that is still possible*, just not with the `import` statement.

As such, there is no cut and dry answer to this question. In principle, any string is valid.

Comment: Thanks for the note about `importlib`.